# Date Format in CSV changed when SSIS package run on Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2008

Data Flow with 2 tasks, Import Flat File ( Source) and Database(Target). I have a source ( csv Flate file ), data type of [Run Date] is DT_STR in the file format, that goes straight to Database Table where the Column [Run Date] is smalldatetime, sql server 2000.

Now I have a [Run Date] Column in my source file like 05/04/2018.

When I run the SSIS package locally, I get 05/04/2018 in my Import Table in the column [Run DATE]. When I run it on the Server, I get 04/05/2018 as [Run DATE]. This is wrong .  How can I ensure SSIS makes the right conversion when it runs the package on the server ? I cannot change the server settings or locale.

Comment: Take a peek at Set DateFormat MDY  or Set DateFormat DMY ...  I'm a little confused as to your desired date format

Comment: 05/04/2018 is correct format for date

Comment: Still ambiguous  MDY or DMY ?

Comment: date format is defined on sql server and it is different from your local machine.
In sql server 2008 and higher you can use SET DATEFORMAT.
As you are using sql server 2000 - you should explicity convert date format. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Comment: DMY . Problem here is that SSIS is making decision about what the string should be when it converts it to a DATE to put in Database Table . If the Server locale is American then it does it wrong. Can SSIS setting be overridden ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can be solved by setting the date format of the operating system. On your server go to the control panel and change the date time format to your preference. That should solve the problem.

Comment: That will work, but its a server with other databases and other SSIS packages on it , so not the option I am going for.

Comment: As far as I remember you can adjust that in the Package properties. look for the attribute "LocaleID"

Comment: Have a look at this link. It should be the option that you are looking for.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c0f52510-4c71-476f-ba1d-643a5d557db0/how-to-change-uk-date-format-to-us-date-format-in-ssis-in-file?forum=sqlintegrationservices